# Loading node into js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am creating a chrome extension that screenshots webshots.

I have create the javascript and HTML files. I am using `node_modules`, which I have saved in the same project folder. When I run the program in the console (`node scripts/screeCapture.js`) everything works perfectly and a screenshot is taken and saved to my computer.

However, I can't get it to work through the extension and it always says that 'required' isn't defined, which I suppose means that `node` isn't being recognized by my programs. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome extension do not use node. Chrome extensions and node are two completely different environments with different APIs, and code that can run in the one environment does not necessarily need to run in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not a browser-based system. You can't "load" Node.js into a browser.

`require` is part of Node's module system (it's a variation on the CommonJS module system, which also uses `require`). Browsers don't use that module system. Until very recently, they didn't use any module system; recently, most of them got support for ES2015's modules (which use `import` and `export` keyword rather than the `require` function and `module.exports` object).

For a Chrome extension, look into using a bundler like Webpack or Rollup.

You may be getting confused by a relatively recent thing where browser-oriented modules (and modules that are neutral, can be used in browsers or Node.js) are being published via `npm`, which was originally a package manager for Node.js modules only. But despite their being published that way, it's not because those modules expect Node.js to be in the browser.

**However**:

> ...everything works perfectly and a screenshot is taken and saved to my computer.

A Node.js module to take screenshots of websites is unlikely to work in a browser or browser extension mechanism (though it *could*, if written to detect its environment). The module you're using probably fires up a headless browser, retrieves the page, and then virtually renders it in order to produce the screenshot. The mechanisms for doing that are completely different in Node.js and in a browser.